# How to keep state of a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, checkbox, local-storage

I have a list of users in 3 different groups(Group A, Group B, and Group C) that I can search by their names. There's a checkbox next to each user. My issue is that even though I click on a checkbox (Example: checkbox next to Alex) and then I start typing Alex I notice my checkbox is no longer checked. I'm guessing it's because React re-renders the component every time I type a character. How can I persist the value of the checkbox? I'm open to using local storage , but what will be the implementation? Thanks in advance!

Here's my [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-cg3fgz?file=/src/components/SearchBar.tsx)

```
<article>
      <h2>
        {post.label}{" "}
        <span onClick={() => setShowGroup(!showGroup)}>
          {showGroup ? "-" : "+"}
        </span>
      </h2>
      {showGroup && (
        <div>
          {post.fields?.map((field: any, idx: number) => {
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
                <span>{field?.name}</span>
                <br />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
</article>
```

Comment: You can store the selected users in a state, so that you can show checked if it is found in the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way will be create state on the app.tsx (Since you are creating some states there already)

```
const [checkboxStates, setCheckboxStates] = useState({});
```

And use it down in the Post (passing this via list component for example)

```
const Post = ({ post, checkboxStates, setCheckboxStates }) => {

 ...

  const handleCheckboxChange = (field, isChecked) => {
    const key = `${post.label}_${field.name}`;
    setCheckboxStates((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: isChecked
    }));
  };

....

<input
 type="checkbox"
 checked={isChecked}
 onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(field, e.target.checked)}
/>

...
```

I forked you live example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-stsx26?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: and how do you select All and deselect All checkboxes? I have posted this other question on here, I'll appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979940/how-to-select-all-and-deselect-all-checkboxes