# How to select All and deselect All checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes that I would like to `selectAll` and `deselectAll` by clicking on either of the **Select All / Deselect All** buttons. I'm able to save the state of each checkbox but having trouble doing a select all/deselect all. Here's my [**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-fkhwfx?file=/src/components/Post.tsx:784-1121)

```
<div>
    {post.fields?.map((field: any, idx: number) => {
      const key = `${post.label}_${field.name}`;
      const isChecked = checkboxStates[key] || false;
      return (
        <div key={idx}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={(e) =>
             handleCheckboxChange(field, e.target.checked)
            }
          />
          <span>{field?.name}</span>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to select All and deselect All checkboxes?

Deselecting all checkboxes is relatively easy since you just need to replace the current `checkboxesState` with an empty object `{}`.

However selecting all checkboxes is lil' bit more complicated since you need to loop over every element in the `data` and add it to the `checkboxesState`.

```
const selectAll = () => {
 setCheckboxStates(() => {
   return searchResults.reduce((acc, next) => {
      next.fields.forEach(({ name }) => {
        acc[`${next.label}_${name}`] = true;
      });

      return acc;
    }, {});
  });
};
```

**[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-xrlpsw?file=/src/components/ListPage.tsx)**